# Unable to delete the file from Perl script

Tags: perl, unix

I have an old perl script which was always working , but suddenly something is broken which is not deleting the file.

```
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   uworld           6 Dec 03 11:15 shot32.file
```

The command to delete the above file is inside a perl script

```
`rm $shotfile`;
```

I have checked $shotfile is shot32.file and it is in the right location.
So file location and filename is not the problem.

Regarding the permission, the perl script is running under nobody user as well , so what could be other reasons for this to not work .

Appreciate your help.

Comment: A Perl program that shells out to delete a file is not a great program! Change `\`rm $shotfile\`` to `unlink $shotfile or die qq{Unable to delete "$shotfile": $!}` and see what error message you get.

Comment: Well, what error did you get? `rm` emits an error message to STDERR on failure.

Answer (score 15):

To delete a file, you need write permissions on the directory the file is in. The permissions on the file don't matter.

That said, that's some pretty awful code you've got there. You're shelling out (without escaping anything, hello shell injection!) just to run `rm` (which you could've run directly without going through the shell), and you're capturing its output for no reason (and you're ignoring whatever was captured anyway). Also, you're not checking for errors (which would be harder in this form as well).

This is all much more complicated than it has to be. Perl has a built-in function for deleting files:

```
unlink $shotfile or warn "$0: can't unlink $shotfile: $!\n";
```

This will delete the file or warn you about any problems (with `$!` containing the reason for the failure). Change `warn` to `die` if you want the program to abort instead.